# ng-show="true" but still has class="ng-hide" angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to show and hide a div. I do it by putting true of false values into the ng-show and ng-hide. I have load this page using ng-include

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <div ng-include="home.html">
    </div>
</body>
```

My home.html

```
<div ng-controller="SubCateCtrl" ng-init="activediv='true'">
    <div class="bcreamb" >
        <a style="" href="#" ng-click="activediv='true'">View</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a ng-click="activediv='false'" href="#">Add</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="activediv">
        <h1>
            View</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="activediv">
        <h1>
            Add</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

For first click Working fine with add button. If I click view button not removing  class="ng-hide" from Add div. it shows like as follows. activediv = false.

```
<div ng-hide="activediv" class="ng-hide">
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do few changes on your code

> Use `href="Javascript:void(0);"` instead of `href"#"` and use `Boolean(true)` value instead of `string('true')` value and use `ng-show="!activediv">` instead of `ng-hide="activediv">`

---

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {   
        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="activediv=true">
    <div class="bcreamb" >
        <a style="" href="Javascript:void(0);" ng-click="activediv= true">View</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a ng-click="activediv=false"  href="Javascript:void(0);">Add</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="activediv">
        <h1>
            View</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!activediv">
        <h1>
            Add</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Hisanth If it works then kindly put mark as this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> - The only thing that you need to do is to change the type of `activediv` from string to bool

---

Put `activediv=true` and `activediv=false` instead of `activediv='true'` and `activediv='false'`.

> **`ng-hide` directive requires a `Boolean` value, not a `string`.**

Comment: I agree! you are correct. That's working for him. But we should be find out the code if questioner makes any mistakes.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. be aware :+1

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

You can directly do in this way:

> Firstly you have to remove `#` from the `href`. Secondly no need to add
>   class `ng-hide` to hide your element

```
<div ng-controller="SubCateCtrl" ng-init="activediv='true'">
    <div class="bcreamb" >
        <a style="" href="" ng-click="activediv='true'">View</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        <a ng-click="activediv='false'" href="">Add</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="activediv">
        <h1>
            View</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!activediv">
        <h1>
            Add</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```